# How to compare instances declared as id<protocol> in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a class that has a property declared as type id that adheres to a protocol and I'd like to ensure equality for it.

How do check for value equality on an property declared as type `id`?

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) id<SomeProtocol> attribute;
@end

@implementation MyClass 

- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
    if (self == object) {
        return YES;
    }

    if (![object isKindOfClass:[MyClass class]]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return [self isEqualToMyClass:(MyClass *) object];
}

- (BOOL)isEqualToMyClass:(MyClass *)rhsValue {
    if (rhsValue == nil) {
        return NO;
    }

    return 
        ([self.name isEqualToString:rhsValue.name] && 
        // Compiler produces error: Error:(90, 36) no known instance method for selector 'isEqual:'
        [self.attribute isEqual:rhs.attribute]); 
}

@end
```

SomeProtocol is defined as:

```
@protocol SomeProtocol <NSObject>

@end
```

Class that extends `SomeProtocol`:

```
@interface MyAttributeClass : NSObject <SomeProtocol>

@end
```

MyAttributeClass implements the protocol `SomeProtocol` and it has its own isEqual and when an instance of it is stored by `MyClass` in attribute, I'd like to be able to check that the values are equivalent.

It is MyAttributeClass that gets assigned into MyClass:

```
MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
myClass.name = "HAL";
myClass.attribute = [[MyAttributeClass alloc] init];
```

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `isEqual:` in the protocol?

Comment: Make sure your `SomeProtocol` protocol extends the `NSObject` protocol.

Comment: Included how SomeProtocol is declared, which does extend NSObject protocol.  I don't have isEqual explicitly declared on SomeProtocol because I assumed that I'd get the ones declared by NSObject.

Comment: Some clarifications: 1. `MyClass` is a subclass of `NSObject`? 2. `rhs.attribute` should be `rhsValue.attribute`?

Comment: MyClass is indeed a subclass of NSObject. (I forgot to type that in when I wrote the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you forgot to import the header containing the protocol definition. (Instead of only having a forward declaration.) Add that in front of the implementation.

Comment: Ah - that was the issue. Thank you!